# (Edited) BackgroundSubtractionMOG2 + Mean-Shift Tracking?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, video-capture, raspberry-pi2

I am doing a project where its a motion based detection program.
However it detects changes in the background as "motion" so i'd like a way to recapture a new first frame every few minutes to replace the current one to fix this issue.
I am using a Raspberry Pi 2B and a Logitech Webcam.
The code i am using is based of : [Pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/01/home-surveillance-and-motion-detection-with-the-raspberry-pi-python-and-opencv/)


This is my version of the code.

Please help me

(Edit)I have changed my code to a BackgroundSubtractionMOG2 now my issue is how do i add Mean-Shift Tracking so that it'll recognize its the same object that entered the screen in the frame earlier?

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils import contours
import datetime
import time

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/pi/Desktop/Proj/VideoTestSample.mp4")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while (cap.isOpened()):
    (grabbed, frame) = cap.read()
    text = " "

    if not grabbed:
        break

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(gray)
    thresh = cv2.erode(fgmask, None, iterations=2)
    (_,cnts,hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for (i,c) in enumerate(cnts):
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 300:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, "#{}".format(i + 1), (x, y - 15),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)        
        text = "REC"

    cv2.putText(frame, "{}". format(text), (10,20),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.putText(frame, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p"),
                (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35,(0,0,255), 1)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
    cv2.imshow('fgmask', fgmask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you want to detect motion, why don't you use a background subtractor like `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorKNN` or `cv2. BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 `?

Comment: @QuangHoang - Isnt it the same as the method i used above? How is it different? (I'm sorry i'm a beginner with only 6 weeks experience with OpenCV)

Comment: It will build background on several frames, not just compare two frames. So the background model is more stable, i.e. less sensitive to _changes in background_

Comment: @QuangHoang - But wouldn't something like that be more... slower? Cause the current method i'm using is slow enough to skip frames so if something go past by too fast it wont be detected